# Convert seconds to mm:ss in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert seconds to minutes and seconds in HH:SS format but my logic don't give me what I want.

```
  static double toMin (var value){
            return (value/60);
          }
```

I also want to be able to add the remainder to the minutes value because sometimes my division gives me a seconds value more that 60 which is not accurate

Comment: `minutes = (seconds modulo 3600) / 60`?

Comment: can you explain how this works?

Comment: Do you mean `mm:ss`?

Comment: @Hamed yes it is

Answer (score 9):

The [`Duration` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Duration-class.html) can do most of the work for you.

```dart
var minutes = Duration(seconds: seconds).inMinutes;
```

You could generate a `String` in a `mm:ss` format by doing:

```dart
String formatDuration(int totalSeconds) {
  final duration = Duration(seconds: totalSeconds);
  final minutes = duration.inMinutes;
  final seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

  final minutesString = '$minutes'.padLeft(2, '0');
  final secondsString = '$seconds'.padLeft(2, '0');
  return '$minutesString:$secondsString';
}
```

That said, I recommend *against* using a `mm:ss` format since, without context, it's unclear whether "12:34" represents 12 minutes, 34 seconds or 12 hours, 34 minutes.  I suggest instead using 12m34s, which is unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  print(toMMSS(100));
}

String toMMSS(int value) =>
    '${formatDecimal(value ~/ 60)}:${formatDecimal(value % 60)}';

String formatDecimal(num value) => '$value'.padLeft(2, '0');
```

or

```dart
String toMMSS(int value) =>
    '${(value ~/ 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(value % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
```

also, you can create an `extension` on `int`:

```dart
extension DateTimeExtension on int {
  String get toMMSS =>
      '${(this ~/ 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(this % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

usage:

```dart
print(342.toMMSS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the solution below, this is how I'm doing it:

```
  String formatHHMMSS(int seconds) {
    if (seconds != null && seconds != 0) {
      int hours = (seconds / 3600).truncate();
      seconds = (seconds % 3600).truncate();
      int minutes = (seconds / 60).truncate();

      String hoursStr = (hours).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
      String minutesStr = (minutes).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
      String secondsStr = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');

      if (hours == 0) {
        return "$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
      }
      return "$hoursStr:$minutesStr:$secondsStr";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```dart
static String formatYMDHMSBySeconds(int milliseconds) {
    if (milliseconds == null) {
        return '';
    }

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds);
    return DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(dateTime);
}
```