# Converting timestamp object to date with difference in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Let’s say I have an object of type `Timestamp` set to 2 days from now.

How to get the `difference` in time and then `format` it in `DateFormat('hh : mm : ss')` in dart ?

Comment: To be clear, are you talking about the [`Timestamp` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/vm_service/latest/vm_service/Timestamp-class.html) from `package:vm_service`?

Comment: yes indeed Sirr

Comment: var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000); you can actually convert your timestamp into Datetime object using this. Pass the int value of the epoch into the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Construct a `DateTime` from the `Timestamp`.
2. Subtract from that `DateTime` the initial time (which I presume should be `DateTime.now()`) to get a `Duration`.
3. Format the `Duration`.  Its default `.toString()` implementation uses hh:mm:ss.microseconds, which is close to what you want.  If you want more control, [you can easily format it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66115260/).

```dart
var dateTime = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.timestamp!);
var duration = dateTime.difference(DateTime.now());
print(duration);
```

Comment: `DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.timestamp!)` is what `aTimeStamp.toDate()` precisely does with less tedium.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz The [`Timestamp` class from `package:vm_service`](https://pub.dev/documentation/vm_service/latest/vm_service/Timestamp-class.html) doesn't seem to have a `toDate()` method, so I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: Oh, I was referring to the FireStore TimeStamp.