# How can i remove unwanted extra double values from timer

Tags: flutter, dart, double

i have the following duration result

```
0:00:01.110000
```

and i am trying to make it look like following , one for minute and one for seconds .. single digit minutes since my case don't require more than 9 minutes

```
0:01
```

the problem i can't control the source of duration because it comes from plugin i use , and i need to handle it in `Text` widget with the previous patron

```
duration myResulDuration  = 0:00:01.110000;
Text(myResulDuration.toString()),

outouts : 0:00:01.110000

wanted result is 0:01
```

How can i achieve with this ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because `0:00:01.110000` is not a `double`, and `double.toString()` would not generate a string `'0:00:01.110000'`.  Do you actually mean that you're getting a [`Duration`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Duration-class.html) object?  If so, see [Convert seconds to mm:ss in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66114340/)

Comment: If it's a string, you can use the `substring` method: `const string = '0:00:01.110000';
final result = string.substring(3, 7); `

Comment: yes @jamesdlin you'r right , but the link you share does not give me the exactly patron i want

Comment: How is the output from the linked question different from what you want?  The linked question asks for `mm:ss` output, which seems to be the same.  The *input* is different (total seconds vs. `Duration`), but the answers could be trivially changed to use `Duration`s directly instead of total seconds (or vice versa).

Comment: @Jack check my answer once and let me know whether it is useful or not

Comment: @jamesdin in that link is mm:ss .. i need m:ss which one digit for minutes only

Comment: @ nagendra nag i can't pass int value as what you explained because my result is duration and not int value

Comment: @jamesdlin i would be grateful if you give me example in answer as m:ss and not mm:ss :)

Comment: Oh, I see.  That's trivial too: just don't use `padLeft` when generating the string for minutes.  You really should try to *understand* the answers instead of copying-and-pasting.

Comment: @jamesdlin you right

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that gives two digits of formatted data

```
String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
```

```
final minutes = twoDigits(myResultTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60));
final seconds = twoDigits(myResultTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60));
```

show these minutes and seconds in Text Widget

```
Text(''$minutes:$seconds')
```

Comment: @ nagendra nag i can't pass int value as what you explained because my result is duration and not int

Comment: `myResultTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60)` it gives integer value