# Flutter video_player Duration?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using the Flutter video_player package here: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

How do I get the duration of the video? I can see there is a `position` property, so I would need that to get the current value in time.

But how do I get the total duration of the video? The video is from a `URL`.

I am making a custom player so I need these two values.

Comment: Follow my ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74872404/16691310

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting the Total duration you can use the video controller

```dart
 VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
      });

 Duration durationOfVideo = _controller.value.duration;
```

You can also directly store the integer instead of duration as below image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to calculate the video Dutarion and format it.

```
  getVideoPosition() {
    var duration = Duration(milliseconds: videoController.value.position.inMilliseconds.round());
    return [duration.inMinutes, duration.inSeconds].map((seg) => seg.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')).join(':');
  }
```

After craeate this function, you just need to call it to show the duration.
Ex.:

```
Text(getVideoPosition())
```